# psycopg2 fetchone() method returning a single-element tuple containing a string representing the «result» tuple

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to write chess-oriented functionalities for a discord bot. 
One of these is to being able to play correspondence games. 
I am using a postgresql database to store every games.

The problem i have is that when i call `cursor.fetchone()` after the execution of a SELECT sql request, the returned object is a single-element tuple containing a string that represents the wanted tuple.

For instance :
`('(351817698172207105,"",1)',)` instead of `(351817698172207105,"",1)`

I installed psycopg2 with pip3 (and using it with python 3.6.7).

I got round that problem by using `ast.literal_eval` in the first SELECT request (creating and accepting a challenge)

But the other request contains the PGN of the game, which contains many quotation marks, and that makes the literal_eval function fail. 
I could mess with the returned str, but i'm not sure it is the best option (and i'd like to understand why it is like this).

The first «get-around» :

```py
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple

cdesc = psycopg2.connect(**params_db)
curs = cdesc.cursor()
modele_req = "SELECT (id_j1, id_j2, id_challenge) FROM challenges WHERE (id_j2='{0}' OR id_j2 = '') AND id_challenge = {1};"

# id_acceptant and id_partie_acceptee are given
req = modele_req.format(id_acceptant, str(id_partie_acceptee))

res_tuple = curs.fetchone()
# print(res_tuple) produces the following output :
# ('(351817698172207105,"",1)',)
(idj1, idj2, idpartie) = make_tuple(res_tuple[0])
```

Also, the following is an example of the returned tuple in the "second" request :

```
(  '("[Event ""?""]\n[Site ""?""]\n[Date ""????.??.??""]\n[Round ""?""]\n[White ""?""]\n[Black ""?""]\n[Result ""*""]\n\n*",351817698172207105,351817698172207105,t)'  ,)
```

When using the make_tuple/literal_eval function, i (obviously) have the following error:

```
(...)
File "/home/synophride/projets/discord_bot/bot/commandes_echecs.py", line 568, in move_bd
    (game_pgn, id_blanc, id_noir, joueur_jouant) = make_tuple(str_tuple)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 59, in _convert
    return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fe1956f5978>
```

In short :

- Is it normal that the cursor.fetchone() method returns that kind of tuple ?
- If no, what did i do wrong and what can i do to rectify that ?

Thanks for reading, and sorry for my eventually dubious english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using brackets in your query, postgres doesnt return the columns (they are stacked into one record).

Your query should look like this, to get all columns:

```
modele_req = "SELECT id_j1, id_j2, id_challenge FROM challenges WHERE ..."
```

Then psycopg2 will return a tuple of 3 items, that is not represented as a string:

```
((351817698172207105,"",1),)
```